# React Native how to wrap component into TouchableOpacity within a Text

Tags: css, react-native, stylesheet, touchableopacity, react-native-stylesheet

I was building **terms and condition** text and I want my **Terms and Conditions** to have a `TouchableOpacity` behavior, same goes to **PrivacyPolicy**

This is what it looks like below:

[image]

Now I want to add `TouchableOpacity` behavior to **Terms & Conditions** same with **Privacy Policy** but when I wrap the **Terms & Conditions** and **Privacy Policy** into `TouchableOpacity` it starts to turn out like this below:

[image]

The Terms & Conditions moved into a new line even thou I'm using `flexWrap: 'wrap'` and there is still space left.

Here is my full code below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  termNConWrapper: {
    ...marginHelper(normalize(4), 0, normalize(5), 0).margin,
    width: wp('80%'),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  termNconAgreement: {
    ...fontHelper(
      10,
      typographyFonts.openSansRegular,
      typographyColors.description,
      0.07,
      16,
    ).font,
    // textAlign: 'center',
  },
  termNcon: fontHelper(
    10,
    typographyFonts.openSansRegular,
    colors.primary,
    0.1,
    16,
  ).font,
});

const OnboardTermsNCondition = () => (
  <View style={styles.termNConWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>
      By clicking Sign Up, you acknowledge that you have read and agree to the
    </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}>{' Terms & Conditions '}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>and</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {/* <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>
      By clicking Sign Up, you acknowledge that you have read and agree to the
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}>{' Terms & Conditions '}</Text>
      and
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
    </Text> */}
  </View>
);
```

Appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

**EDIT:** I tried removing the helper styles but still no luck. Here is the full code below:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
// import {  } from 'native-base';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { fontHelper, marginHelper } from 'constants/theme/helpers';
import { typographyFonts, colors, typographyColors } from 'constants/theme';
import { normalize } from 'utils/normalize';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  termNConWrapper: {
    // ...marginHelper(normalize(4), 0, normalize(5), 0).margin,
    // width: wp('80%'),
    // flexDirection: 'row',
    // flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  termNconAgreement: {
    // ...fontHelper(
    //   10,
    //   typographyFonts.openSansRegular,
    //   typographyColors.description,
    //   0.07,
    //   16,
    // ).font,
    // textAlign: 'center',
  },
  termNcon: {},
});

const OnboardAgreement = () => (
  <View style={styles.termNConWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>
      By clicking Sign Up, you acknowledge that you have read and agree to the
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
        <Text style={styles.termNcon}>{' Terms & Conditions '}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      and
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
        <Text style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Text>
  </View>
);

const MemoizedOnboardAgreement = memo(OnboardAgreement);

export { MemoizedOnboardAgreement as OnboardAgreement };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Text as the wrapper instead of the view

```
  <Text style={styles.termNConWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>
      By clicking Sign Up, you acknowledge that you have read and agree to the
    </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}>{' Terms & Conditions '}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>and</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {/* <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>
      By clicking Sign Up, you acknowledge that you have read and agree to the
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}>{' Terms & Conditions '}</Text>
      and
      <Text style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
    </Text> */}
  </Text>
```

Couldnt check the styles as you have a style helper but it should work.

Or you can use the onPress of Text component which you can use instead of the TouchableOpacity and will make it easier for you to style as well

```
 <Text onPress={()=>{alert(123)}} style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
```

Comment: the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy is not showing when I did this.

Comment: Can you share your custom styles ?

Comment: @joyce better check your custom style helper and the styles for the wrapper

Comment: I tried removing the styles but the text inside touchable opacity is still not showing. I'm using React Native 0.62.2

Comment: Another solution is to use the onpress of text rather than using touchable opacity  <Text onPress={()=>{alert(123)}} style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text> this will work as well and easy to style too

Comment: @joyce can you try the onpress of text instead of the touchableopacity ?

Comment: it can be but I wanted to add that opacity effect on being pressed of the text.

Comment: Seems like the touchable opacity doenst work on ios :(

Comment: even on Android I receive an error says that **Cannot Add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent with out a measure function**

Comment: Yes, i think you will have to go for the onclick alternative :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to place everything inside one single Text Component.

**Code:**

```
   <Text style={styles.termNconAgreement}>
      By clicking Sign Up, you acknowledge that you have read and agree to the
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
        <Text style={styles.termNcon}>{' Terms & Conditions '}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      and
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4}>
        <Text style={styles.termNcon}> Privacy Policy</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Text>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/HD8NeugqV

Comment: the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy is not showing when I did this.

Comment: @joyce try out my demo, it is working fine. Maybe you have another issue

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I don't know what's different its the like your demo.

Comment: @joyce try to remove your custom styles (termNcon, termNconAgreement ...). Then try it again please. In my demo i did not use your styles, probably that's the issue.

Comment: @joyce please update your question and add your current code.